# Unable to call AddRange on DbSet test double

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I'm refactoring a section of legacy code to be more testable. A part of that is to implement a test double of the entity framework `DbSet`. I've followed the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/writing-test-doubles and it works fine.

The existing class uses `AddRange` so I added an override to the TestDbSet class.

```
public override IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        yield return Add(entity);
    }
}
```

And I tried calling it

```
myDbContext.Persons.AddRange(newPersons);
```

However `AddRange` never gets called. If I comment `AddRange` out I get a `NotImplementedException` from the DbSet class.

I've started a new project from scratch and `AddRange` works as expected. So I must have something that is interfering with it in my project however I'm unable to determine the cause.

What could prevent my override from being called in my derived class of `DbSet`?

My work around for now is to use Add instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I messed around and removed the yield statement. Suddenly it works. No idea why.

```
public override IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        _data.Add(entity);
    }
    return entities;
}
```